# How to Fetch/Insert in Database without Sql Query

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database

I am trying to get customers from the database whose order was cancelled, and I am able to do this via Query. But I think the standard way should be without using Queries. So is there a way I can accomplish this? I searched on google but result is quite ambiguous and mostly for Magento 1.x where as I need for Magento 2.3.

My Query:

```
SELECT customer_id, count(`entity_id`) as custCount from $tableName WHERE `status` = 'cancel'
```

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the order collection of Magento

```
$collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['eq' => 'cancel']);
```

Maybe this link can help you:
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/get-all-order-collection-filters-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Your can get customers details whose orders are cancelled by this way

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
  ) {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }
public function getCustomerCollection() {
        $customerIdArray = array();
        $collection = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['eq' => 'cancel']);
        foreach ($collection as $items) {
            array_push($customerIdArray, $items['customer_id']);
        }
        $customerCollection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $CustomerIdArray));        
        return $customerCollection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use magento standard as below using collections

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
  ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }
public function execute() {
        $collection = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', ['eq' => 'cancel']);

        var_dump($collection->getSelect());
    }
```